# Stop form submission with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have been making a javascript form validator to provide live form validation. If there is an error it should stop the submission but it doesn't. I have tried returning false and using preventDefault() but it still doesn't prevent submission. I have tried to find the answer else where but I can't, so can any of you help me out.

The form is on http://swanleyhypnotherapist.co.uk/contact.html.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you paste the relevant code into this post, please?

Answer (score 2):

#### Simple mistake.

Replace:

```
<form name="contact" action="/" onsubmit="check();">
```

With:

```
<form name="contact" action="/" onsubmit="return check();">
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed it but it still doesn't work. What else have I done wrong.

Comment: Okay, have you updated it in the website? Can I check it live?

Comment: @user2001154 Give `return false;` before `event.preventDefault();` or remove `event.preventDefault();` for now and check. Also, remove the `evt` parameter.

Comment: Sorry. I was busy so I have only just checked it. It does appear to work. I didn't at first add preventDefault() but I tried it when it wasn't working. The problem must have been leaving out return in the onsubmit attribute and when I corrected it the preventDefault I had added was the problem. Thanks for your help guys.